# Are infinite loops truly infinite?

Tags: loops, logic

I have a pretty good understanding of loops in general, and have accidentally created infinite loops several times while programming in various languages.

However, is an infinite loop truly infinite? If given unlimited resources and time, would an infinite loop run for all eternity?

I'm not sure if this is on topic or not, but I figured it was due to it being programming logic. If not, just comment and I'll remove the question (I want to keep the little rep I have).

Comment: Yes, of course. Why wouldn't it, unless the hardware died first?

Comment: Well, it's not infinite if the power goes out. And are you accounting for the  the inevitable heat death of the universe?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is virtually a religious question of the nature of eternity, the fate of the universe and whether or not you can indefinitely afford to pay the power bill to keep your computer running.

Comment: Understood, can you just remove it? @Bohemian

Comment: @Ellis it will get vacuumed up automatically after a while, You can delete it yourself if you want

Comment: @Bohemian all right, thanks, sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An infinite loop will normally run until it is interrupted externally. If anything is allocated inside the loop, however, the application may run out of memory, or, especially with a recursive call, you could get a "Stack Overflow" that stops the application.